# How do I Mod_Rewrite Entire URL Path?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have been using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Which will turn

```
example.com/page/hello
```

...into

```
example.com/index.php?page/hello
```

However, if I have a file extension on the end of that, say,

```
example.com/page/hello/doc.html
```

...it doesn't work. How can I make that URL become:

```
example.com/index.php?page/hello/doc.html
```

...and

```
example.com/page/
```

...become:

```
example.com/index.php?page/
```

Thank you very much if you are able to help with this. I've tried fiddling with the regular expression, but I just can't make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of your regex will match one or more characters that are anything except a full stop:

```
[^\.]+
```

If you want to match one or more of any character, then just write:

```
.+
```

instead